# List Permutations

Tags: javascript, string, permutation, combinations

I'm trying to list all three letter permutations and this is the code I have -

```
  window.permute = function(){
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var searchTerm ="aaa";
    var position = 2; 
    changeString(searchTerm, position); 
}

window.changeString = function(searchTerm, position){
    if (position <0){
        alert(newString);

    return; 
    }
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for (j=0; j < 26;j++){
        var newString = searchTerm.substr(0, position) + alphabet[j] + searchTerm.substr(position+1);
        var newPosition = position -1; 
        changeString(newString,newPosition);
    }
    return;
}
```

It's not working and I'm not sure why- can anyone help?

Comment: Could you provide some more context?

Comment: er, right now I'm only getting the first letter to change- I need all permutations

Comment: This may or may not matter, but know that what you are trying to do is generate 26!/(26-3)! = 15,600 strings.

Answer (score 4):

```
var permutate = (function() {
    var results = [];    
    function doPermute(input, output, used, size, level) {        
        if (size == level) {
            var word = output.join('');
            results.push(word);
            return;
        } 
        level++;
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (used[i]) {
                continue;
            }            
            used[i] = true;
            output.push(input[i]);
            doPermute(input, output, used, size, level);
            used[i] = false;
            output.pop();
        }
    }

    return {
        getPermutations: function(input, size) {
            var chars = input.split('');
            var output = [];
            var used = new Array(chars.length);      
            doPermute(chars, output, used, size, 0);        
            return results;    
        }
    }
})();
```

for more information, visit http://jinwolf.tumblr.com/post/26476479113/draw-something-cheat
for an working example, check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jinwolf/Ek4N5/31/

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(newString);
```

`newString` is not defined right there. Instead, you should use the argument passed:

```
alert(searchTerm);
```

---

**Edit:** I'm not entirely sure of your approach. It seems overly complicated. This seems to work. I understand that you rather have your own code working, but perhaps this helps you in solving. I don't quite get your `substr` part.

http://jsfiddle.net/NUG2A/2/

```
var alphabet = "abc"; // shortened to save time

function permute(text) {
    if(text.length === 3) { // if length is 3, combination is valid; alert
        console.log(text); // or alert
    } else {
        var newalphabet = alphabet.split("").filter(function(v) {
            return text.indexOf(v) === -1;
        }); // construct a new alphabet of characters that are not used yet
            // because each letter may only occur once in each combination

        for(var i = 0; i < newalphabet.length; i++) {
            permute(text + newalphabet[i]); // call permute with current text + new
                                            // letter from filtered alphabet
        }
    }
}

permute("");
```

This will result in the following being called:

```
permute("");
permute("a");
permute("ab");
permute("abc"); // alert
permute("ac");
permute("acb"); // alert
permute("b");
// ...
```

Comment: *facepalm - even with that though, I'm only getting the first letter changed

Comment: which means that one of the returns isn't doing what I want it to do

Comment: What you're producing is a [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), not the permutations.

Comment: @pimvdb: he might want the power set, if so that's a paltry 2^26 = 67,108,864 strings...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from your question that you mean "permutations" because usually permutations do not include repeated elements where it looks like you want to include "aaa".

Here are [several algorithms](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/permutation.shtml) for listing permutations you can go check out. If it turns out you mean to have repetitions, it looks like pimvdb has you covered.

**Edit:** So you know what you are getting into run-time wise:

- With repetition (aaa,aab,...): n^k = 26^3 = 17,576
- Without repetition (abc,bac,...): n!/(n-k)! = 26!/(26-3)! = 15,600

Comment: It's not in the combinations either. The combinations of a set is the set of set of permutations taken regardless of order, not permutations from a set with replacement.

Comment: True, I was abusing the definitions, I threw that out and just used permutations "with" and "without" repetition.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (j=0; j < 26;j++){
```

should be

```
for (var j=0; j<26; j++) {
```

Without the declaration, `j` is a global variable, so it only takes one iteration to get to `26` and then all the loops terminate.

Comment: wait- that makes a difference?- how come there were no errors in the console?

Comment: @scubadiver oh yeah you have no idea how subtle the effects of the auto global declaration is

Answer (score 0):

For permutations a recursive algorith as pimvd showed is always nice but don't forget you can just brute force it with for-loops when N is small:

```
for(int x1=0; x1 < 26; x1++)
for(int x2=0; x2 < 26; x2++)
for(int x3=0; x3 < 26; x3++){
    //do something with x1, x2, x3
}
```

Answer (score -3):

In C#:

```
    void DoPermuation(string s)
    {
        var pool = new HashSet<string>();
        //Permute("", , pool);
        pool = Permute(new List<char>(s));
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in pool) Console.WriteLine("{0:D2}: {1}", ++i, item);      
    }

    HashSet<string> Permute(List<char> range)
    {
        if (range.Count == 1) return new HashSet<string>(new string[] { range[0].ToString() });

        var pool = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var c in range)
        {             
            var list = new List<char>(range);
            list.Remove(c);
            foreach (var item in Permute(list)) pool.Add(c + item);                
        }

        return pool;
    }
```

Comment: Presumably if an answer in C# was desired, that would have been indicated in the question.